# Какой способ установки положения матрицы-модели оптимальный?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, opengl, матрицы

Допустим, есть матрица модели `model`, назовём её «игроком».

```
model = glm::mat4(1.0);
```

На игрока, возможно, были наложены эффекты масштабирования, поворота и перемещения.

```
model = glm::scale(...);
model = glm::rotate(...);
model = glm::translate(...);
```

Теперь мне нужно установить новое положение этому игроку относительно не самого игрока (что делает метод translate), а относительно «мира», то есть относительно начала мировых координат <0, 0, 0>.

Решение, которое сразу приходит на ум, следующее:

```
model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), glm::vec3(x, y, z));
```

Проблема в том, что из за того, что матрица модели `model` заменяется матрицей `glm::mat4(1)`, все раннее наложенные эффекты масштабирования и поворота исчезают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно эти матрицы перемножают непосредственно перед отрисовкой, чтобы передавать для отрисовки в шейдер 1 итоговую матрицу Модели (игрока).

Сами же координаты игрока хранятся и используются в более простом виде - "положение", "куда смотрит" и "масштаб". Т.к. для почти любых игровых нужд, удобнее иметь положение `XYZ`, направление взгляда `Heading`/`Pitch` и размер `Scale`, а не матрицы 4х4.

То же самое относится к и помогает моделям интерполяции/экстраполяции, если, например, у вас игровая логика работает на точных 30фпс, а отрисовка динамическая 30-120фпс в зависимости от мощности GPU.

Comment: То есть, мне следует хранить хранить лишь координаты в виде `glm::vec3`, вместо `glm::mat4`, и перед каждым рисованием создавать новую матрицу модели и передать шейдеру, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Обычно так делается, да. "Стоимость" данной операции наносекунды. Удобство использования - экономит часы, дни и недели в разработке и отладке.